# How to pass Type at Runtime to Polymorphic function scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, polymorphism, scala-reflect

Below is a sample example. Where i need to convert value stored in String as a Type and pass that to polymorphic function in scala.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.api

object Test {

    def convert[T](l: String)(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): T = l.asInstanceOf[T]

    implicit def stringToTypeTag[A](name: String): TypeTag[A] = {
        val c = Class.forName(name)
        val mirror = runtimeMirror(c.getClassLoader)
        val sym = mirror.staticClass(name)
        val tpe = sym.selfType
        TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
            def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
                if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
                else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
        })
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        val typ = "Integer"
        val x = convert("10")(stringToTypeTag("java.lang." + typ))
        val y = convert("20")(stringToTypeTag("java.lang." + typ))

        println(x.getClass)
        println(y.getClass)

        val z = x + y
        println(z)

        // Expected OP 30

        val typ = "String"
        val x1 = convert("10")(stringToTypeTag("java.lang." + typ))
        val y1 = convert("20")(stringToTypeTag("java.lang." + typ))

        println(x1.getClass)
        println(y1.getClass)

        val z1 = x1 + y1
        println(z1)
        // Expected OP 1020

    }
}
```

> Expected OP: 30 when Integer and 1020 when String

Comment: What exactly is the question? - But more importantly, why? Runtime reflection is extremely difficult and unsafe, overall the code will not take advantages of the **Scala**'s advanced type system. Thus, its use should be limited to cases where it is absolutely necessary. - If you can share your original problem, maybe we can recommended a different approach.

Comment: This is a sample example for explanation. Actually I am loading various parameters from config file and need to convert value to type loaded from config file.

Comment: Have you taken a look to [**pureconfig**](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig)?

Comment: Here is my complete scenarios - args { runDate = { type = int, required = true } , schema = { type = String }. This is loaded using pure config. Now i planning to use existing options parser scpopt or scallop. To create a argunemnt option i need to call opt[String] or opt[Int], this string / int are coming from config and i need to convert them to type so that i can pass them to this function and a type

Comment: I think it would be better if you close this question and open a new one with your current problem, example input, expected output and all the code you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

There are too many problems in this code, I am stating just the most obvious one as the deeper problems require a blog and not an answer.

So, this method,

```
def convert[T](l: String)(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): T = l.asInstanceOf[T]
```

The most obvious problem here is trying to convert a `String` to `T` by using `l.asInstanceOf[T]`. This is not how things work, you can not just convert a `String` to a `T` by doing `asInstanceOf`. Let me show when is this `asInstanceOf` can be used.

```
// Lets say, there was an Int
scala> val i: Int = 10
// i: Int = 10

// but it was somehow assigned to a variable of type Any
scala> val a: Any = i
// a: Any = 10

// Now, even if we know that the value is an Int 
// but since the variable is Any, we can not do Int like things on it
scala> a / 2
// <console>:13: error: value / is not a member of Any .
//       a / 2
//         ^

// you can use `asInstanceOf` again access it as an Int
scala> a.asInstanceOf[Int] / 2
// res4: Int = 5
```

But only because the `value` was already an `Int`, just the `variable` was of type `Any`.

What you are trying to do, it to cast a `value` of type `String` to some `T`.

Other than this you are mixing a lot of compile time things with run time things, which will not work out for a lot of reasons.

You should look into a config library such as lightbend-config or pureconfig. Or a reader implementation such as following.

```
trait ConfigReader[A] {
  def read(input: String): A
}

object ConfigReader {

  object Implicits {

    implicit val intConfigReader = new ConfigReader[Int] {
      override def read(input: String): Int = input.toInt
    }

    implicit val doubleConfigReader = new ConfigReader[Double] {
      override def read(input: String): Double = input.toDouble
    }

    implicit val stringConfigReader = new ConfigReader[String] {
      override def read(input: String): String = input
    }

  }

  def read[A](input: String)(implicit configReader: ConfigReader[A]) = configReader.read(input)


}

import ConfigReader.Implicits._

val i = ConfigReader.read[Int]("5")

val d = ConfigReader.read[Double]("5.0")
```

Comment: I don't know the datatype until runtime so I would need to write implicit for all scenarios...

Comment: I think it is worth to clarify that there aren't **types** on runtime, only **classes**. And that `isInstanceOf` work on the latter. So on your example, `i` was not of type _Int_, it was _Any_. But its class was _Int_ that is why the `asInstanceOf` works.

Comment: @arjunchopra The moment you say that only runtime knows what type that String is supposed to be then things become a lot complicated. The approach will be to lift things up into your own "Repr Implementation". But then you need to ensure that your "Repr implelmentation" supports all operations you require, and you map out of your lifted context only when you no longer need it (when saving to db or printing etc). Slick has one of the best lifted contexts, but you will not need anything remotely as sophisticated for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work because function polymorphism is done at compile time, not run time. So you can't select a polymorphic function based on the name of a type that is read from a file.

The underlying problem is that the type of a variable is determined at compile time. So the compiler has to pick the type of `x` and `y` *before* the type is read from the configuration. Since `x` and `y` could one of a number of types, the compiler probably chooses `Any`.

This is theoretically OK so far because an `Any` variable can hold either `Int` or `String`. But things go wrong when you try to add them: `x + y`. This is telling the compiler to add an `Any` to an `Any` and this is clearly going to go badly. The program does not use the run-time type of `x` and `y` to pick the appropriate `+` function.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the new requirement details given in the comments, you can do something like following.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

case class Repr[+A: ClassTag](value: A)

def readInputAsRepr(
  input: String,
  valueType: String
): Try[Repr[Any]] =
  valueType match {
    case "Int" => Try(Repr[Integer](input.toInt))
    case "Double" => Try(Repr[Double](input.toDouble))
    case "String" => Try(Repr[String](input))
    case _ => Failure(new UnsupportedOperationException)
  }

def intSumAction(i1: Int, i2: Int) = i1 + i2
def doubleSumAction(d1: Double, d2: Double) = d1 + d2
def stringSumAction(s1: String, s2: String) = s1 + s2

def selectAndEvaluateAction(
  repr1: Repr[Any],
  repr2: Repr[Any]
): Try[Repr[Any]] =
  (repr1.value, repr2.value) match {
    case (a1: Int, a2: Int) => Success(Repr(intSumAction(a1, a2)))
    case (a1: Double, a2: Double) => Success(Repr(doubleSumAction(a1, a2)))
    case (a1: String, a2: String) => Success(Repr(stringSumAction(a1, a2)))
    case _ => Failure(new UnsupportedOperationException)
  }

val x1 = readInputAsRepr("10", "Int").get
val y1 = readInputAsRepr("20", "Int").get
val z1 = selectAndEvaluateAction(x1, y1)

val x2 = readInputAsRepr("10", "String").get
val y2 = readInputAsRepr("20", "String").get
val z2 = selectAndEvaluateAction(x2, y2)
```